# Coordinates for vertices of the "silver" rhombohedron.

Tags: solid-geometry

The "silver" [rhombohedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombohedron) (a.k.a the trigonal trapezohedron) is a three-dimensional object with six faces composed of congruent rhombi. You can see it visualised [here](http://edobobik.kilu.de/silveroblaterhombohedron.html).

I am interested in replicating the visualisation linked to above in MATLAB, but to do that I need to know the coordinates of the rhombohedron's eight vertices (I am using the *patch* function).

How do I calculate the coordinates of the vertices of the silver rhombohedron?

Answer (score 1):

Use vectors $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(\cos{\alpha},\sin{\alpha},0)$ and $e_3=(\cos{\alpha},0,\sin{\alpha})$ as basis.
Then vertices are set of all points with each coordinate $0$ or $1$: $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1)$, ..., $(1,1,1)$.
Or $0$, $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, $e_1+e_2$, ..., $e_1+e_2+e_3$.

Multiply coordinates by constant if needed.